# Nuget Push in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

So Nuget (v4) comes for free with VS2017. To pack a project we do the folling ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017))

```
msbuild /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release
```

Great. But is there an msbuild command that enables me to push to a repository? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/publish-a-package) seem to indicate that I still need to use `nuget.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for that you still have to use `nuget.exe push` or `dotnet nuget push` (provided .net core CLI is installed).

Comment: Is it still the same in 2019?

Comment: @KishanVaishnav yes